# C# ASP.NET странная ошибка при вызове метода из проекта Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.NET MVC / использую VkNet для публикации записей в группу в ВК

В определенное время планировщик заданий делает GET-запрос с ключем на определенный `Action` (https://mydomain.com/Service/Vk?key=SECRET_KEY)

После выполняется логика `Action` и в конце делается вызов метода отвечающего за работу с VkNet:

```
VkontakteService.WallPost(APPID, "LOGIN", "PWD", OWNERID, message);
```

**Метод:**

```
public static void WallPost(ulong appId, string login, string password, long ownerId, string message)
{
    try
    {
        VkApi api = new VkApi();
        api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
        {
            ApplicationId = appId,
            Login = login,
            Password = password,
            Settings = Settings.All
        });

        api.Wall.Post(new WallPostParams
        {
            OwnerId = ownerId,
            FromGroup = true,
            Message = message,
            Signed = false,
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Ошибка при добавлении записи в группу ВК: {ex}");
    }
}
```

В итоге получаю странный `Exception`:

```
[2016-11-21 23:13:11.3353][Error]: Ошибка при добавлении записи в группу ВК: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at VkNet.VkApi.Call(String methodName, VkParameters parameters, Boolean skipAuthorization)
   at VkNet.Categories.WallCategory.Post(WallPostParams params)
   at MyProject.Services.VkontakteService.WallPost(UInt64 appId, String login, String password, Int64 ownerId, String message) in D:\MyProject\trunk\Sources\MyProject.Services\VkontakteService.cs:line 27

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/MyProject/trunk/Sources/MyProject.Host/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\MyProject\trunk\Sources\MyProject.Host\bin
Calling assembly : VkNet, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\MyProject\trunk\Sources\MyProject.Host\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Home\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ee02bc37/45707ec2/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ee02bc37/45707ec2/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/MyProject/trunk/Sources/MyProject.Host/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Сам класс `VkontakteService` с методом `WallPost` лежат в соседнем проекте (Class Library) с подключенным VkNet

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.5" newVersion="1.4.9.5" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, может кто сталкивался с такими ошибками, я просто впервые вижу такой странный лог?

Comment: Приведите package.config

Comment: возможно стоит сделать restore package всем проектам в решении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VkNet версии 1.21 [использует](https://github.com/vknet/vk/blob/v1.21.0.0/VkNet/packages.config) пакет Newtonsoft.Json версии 8.0.0.2

При этом в разделе Dependencies в nuget стоит >= - потому и подтянулась последняя версия. Это ошибка авторов библиотеки VkNet.

Вам надо сделать одно из трех действий:

1. Обновить VkNet до последней версии
2. Даунгрейднуть Newtonsoft.Json до версии 8.0.0.2
3. Прописать перенаправление (assemblyBinding) для сборки Newtonsoft.Json с версии 8.0.0.2 до 9.0.0.1 в файле web.config

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: помог даунгрейд Newtonsoft.Json и потом пришлось еще сделать даунгрейд для HtmlAgilityPack, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3):

Возможно VkNet требует версию Newtonsoft.Json выше чем вы используете

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json подтянулся сам при добавлении VkNet...

Comment: @tCode я проверил - при добавлении VkNet подтягивается нужная версия Newtonsoft.Json. Скорее всего, более новая версия у вас подтянулась вместе с ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @PavelMayorov как быть?

Comment: @tCode я же написал в своем ответе

Comment: @PavelMayorov а, ок

Answer (score 1):

Исключение говорит о том, что не удается загрузить версию сборки `Newtonsoft.Json  Version=9.0.0.0`. Как только возникает проблема с NuGet-пакетами, могут помочь некие *танцы с бубном*, а именно:

1. Очистить решение (лучше руками все почистить дополнительно);
2. Восстановить Ваши NuGet-пакеты, правой кнопкой мыли по решению `Restore NuGet Packages` (убедиться в том, что нужный NuGet-пакет появился у Вас в папке packages для NuGet-пакетов) либо переустановить необходимый NuGet-пакет через `Package Manager Console`;
3. Убедиться в том, что ссылки в проекте указывают на существующую
   версию NuGet-пакетов (Конфиги и файлы проектов);
4. Перестроить решение и попробовать снова.

На GitHub нашел использование `VkNet Version=1.21.0.0`, она используется совместно с `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0`. [Ссылка на источник](https://github.com/jonkoops/pirate/blob/master/Pirate/Pirate.vbproj). Видимо имеется смысл понизить версию `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Если углубиться в исключение (`Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040`), то можно узнать, что код исключения означает, попытку вызвать метод из сборки, которого не существует. Иными словами, разница в версиях `Newtonsoft.Json`. В одной версии что-то есть, в другой этого нет. Отсюда и появляются подводные камни. Можно попробовать сначала понизить версию `Newtonsoft.Json`, если не поможет - попробовать восстановить пакеты (не смотря на то, что говорят в комментариях).

Comment: Не помогут эти танцы - потому что версии загружаемых библиотек от них не изменятся, они останутся несовместимыми.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тут два варианта на самом деле. Первый - это то, что пишется в исключении, не может найти библиотеку, а второй я дополнил в ответе - использовать более низкую версию `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а Вы мне минус влупили за то, что я поделился возможными вариантами решения проблемы, которые ранее мне помогли, но которые не удовлетворили Вас?

Comment: Нет, потому что эти варианты не помогут в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: Решение очищал, восстанавливал пакеты - не помоло, вечером попробую переписать версию в app.config